# Application could not be uploaded to the device with XF

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm on the most recent VSMac, most recent X.iOS, and Forms.  xcode is upto date and my mac is upto date.  I'm running on an intel mac, but I can't imagine that is causing problems.  I have an XF app.  It runs.  I just deployed a new version about 2 weeks ago.  I'm updating my certs.  Everything compiles.  I have updated my certs, provisioning profile and installed them.  I am getting this HE0004 error when I attempt to deploy.  I found some other references to this on SO, but this seemed to be early on the release cycle of a version of XCode.  Any suggestions on how to resolve it?  TIA.

/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mlaunch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --installdev "/Users/wallym/Projects/GolfGameScanApp/GolfGameScanApp/GolfGameScanApp.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad13.18-16.4.1/GolfGameScanApp.iOS.app" --device ios "--devname=Wallace McClure’s iPad" --install-progress
error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'ContentDeliveryServices' (path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/ContentDeliveryServices):
dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/ContentDeliveryServices, 0x0001): Library not loaded: @rpath/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery
Referenced from: <77B7BF95-A673-3DD7-875F-6393D0092351> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.2.0.5/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.2.0.5/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.2.0.5/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/../ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.2.0.5/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/../ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/ContentDelivery.framework/Versions/A/ContentDelivery' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

Application could not be uploaded to the device.

Comment: Which version of Xcode?  The last time I checked Xamarin had not released support for the latest release

Comment: @jason this is xcode 14.3

Comment: According to [Xcode 14.3 Support for Xamarin, .NET 6/7 and MAUI #17561](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561), `Xcode 14.3` is not supported, and it is recommended that you use `Xcode 14.2` for now. If you have updated to `Xcode 14.3` and want to go back to `Xcode 14.2` you can download `Xcode 14.2` from the [downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) in the Apple Developer Portal.